# Как задействовать скрипт в файле загружаемом по get?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

На сайте есть кнопки для рейтинга новости

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="doRate('5', '10930'); return false;">супер</li>
    <li onclick="doRate('4', '10930'); return false;">хорошо</li>           
    <li onclick="doRate('3', '10930'); return false;">нормально</li>
    <li onclick="doRate('2', '10930'); return false;">плохо</li>
    <li onclick="doRate('1', '10930'); return false;">ужасно</li>
</ul>
```

при выставлении оценки они подгружают файл `engine/ajax/rating.php`

```
function doRate(a, c) {
  ShowLoading("");
  $.get("/engine/ajax/rating.php", {
    go_rate: a,
    news_id: c
  }, function(a) {
    HideLoading("");
    if (a.success) {
      var d = a.rating,
        d = d.replace(/&lt;/g, "<"),
        d = d.replace(/&gt;/g, ">"),
        d = d.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
      $("#ratig" + c).html(d);
      $("#vote" + c).html(a.votenum)
    }
  }, "json")
}
```

Почему в этом файле не работают скрипты?

Пишу так

```
echo '<script>Materialize.toast("текст", 5000);</script>';
```

Даже простой `alert` не работает.

Comment: и что выводит файл rating.php?

Comment: Ничего. Там запрос в бд и тп